# Braintree: how to show stored payment methods with some card info in custom UI

Tags: braintree

Basically what I want to do is show a list of stored payment methods of the customer so they can pick an existing one instead of putting in credit card info.

I know I can store customerId and payment token in my server. But I need a way to present and map the token to some basic card info (such as Visa, last for digits, Name), so the user would know which is which. And upon user submitting the form, I need to know which token they've selected.

What's the best way of achieving this?

Answer (score 1):

<sub>Full disclosure: I work at Braintree. If you have any further questions, feel free to contact [support](https://www.braintreepayments.com/contact).</sub>

With a `customer_id`, you can call [`Braintree::Customer.find("customer_id")`](https://www.braintreepayments.com/contact) to get a `Customer` object, and then call `customer.payment_methods` to get the list of payment methods associated with that specific customer.
The list of attributes of each `PaymentMethod` object will differ depending on whether it is a credit card, PayPal account, or Apple or Android Pay Card. For example, you can find the attributes for a credit card payment method [on this page](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/response/credit-card/ruby).

Each `PaymentMethod` object will also have a token, so when the user selects one of the payment methods, you can use that token to [create the transaction](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/request/transaction/sale/ruby#payment_method_token).